# How to define extra dynamic field based on Foreign Key model field in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, foreign-keys

I am trying to make extra display field in form that used to take value based on changing the related table field.

suppose

**model.py**

```
# Create model.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    model2 = models.ForeignKey(MyModel2)

class MyModel2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    description = models.CharField()
```

**forms.py**

```
# Create forms.py
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    extraField = forms.CharField(disabled=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        field = '__all__'
```

In this particular `extraField`. I need to related this field with `model2.description` value.
Is there any way to do this.

Comment: Just change model to `MyModel2` in `Meta class`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to set mymodel2.description to the extra form field on form_valid? If so:

In your view (I'm assuming class-based views):

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    with transaction.atomic():  # in case model2 save fails
        instance = form.save()
        instance.model2.description = form.cleaned_data['extrafield']
        instance.model2.save()
```

The transaction makes sure that both models are saved, or neither is.

Comment: Thanks for giving you time to this. But sorry to say. It can't be helpful. I think I'm unable to give you clarity towards particular concern.
Let's say -- **MyForm()** having _name_, _model2_ and _extraField_ fields. While on changing field of **model2**, the **extraField** will auto changed to **description** of model2 object.